# Htaccess Headers Set on 301 Not on 200

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, response-headers

I have an .htaccess file with the following rewrite rules. The first section is to prepend "www" to domains that don't have an existing 3rd level domain (e.g. are not named. sub.example.com or [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) and the second to convert to https if they do have a 3rd level domain:

```
# BEGIN RewriteRules
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
# Check if Host is not empty, check it hasn't got a 3rd level domain
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.(co\.uk|org\.uk|uk|com|org)+$
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
# Check if https is not enabled as all domains are now https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END Rewrite Rules
```

The second section is standard Wordpress multisite rewrites:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteBase /web
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]  
# Add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
    RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L] 
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I then have a set of headers I ask to be set:

```
# BEGIN Headers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
# Remove server headers
    Header always unset Location
    Header always unset X-Powered-By
    Header always unset X-Redirect-By
# Set server headers
    Header always set Vary "Accept-Encoding, User-Agent"
    Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
# PHP/HTML Doesn't show for root URL
    Header always set Connection "keep-alive"
    Header always set Referrer-Policy "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"
    Header always set X-DNS-Prefetch-Control "on"
    Header always set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
    Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
# Set Cache-Control
    <FilesMatch "\.(php|x?html?)$">
        Header always set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate, max-age=31536000"
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|svg|webp|swf|css|webm|mp4|ttf|woff|woff2)$">
        Header always set Cache-Control "must-revalidate, public, max-age=31536000"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
        Header always set Cache-Control "private, max-age=31536000"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(pdf|xlsx?|docx?|pptx?|zipx?)$">
        Header always set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate, max-age=31536000"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
# END Headers
```

The headers set correctly on css, js, images etc, and also set on the original 301 request.
For example, I can see them set on the 301 request for http://example.com, but once that redirects to https://www.example.com, the headers are missing.

If I go directly to https://www.example.com, the headers are still missing.

Does anyone know why and how to rectify this?

Comment: " I can see them set on the 301 request for `http://example.com`" - Presumably you mean, "on the 301 _response from_ `http://example.com`"? Do you use a front-end proxy or CDN? By "the headers", do you mean _all_ the response headers? `Header always unset Location` - isn't that a bit of a weird one? If that was honoured, wouldn't it break the canonical redirects?

Comment: @mrwhite Yes, sorry, I meant the response headers. I don't use a Proxy or CDN. And I can't remember why I unset Location! I may just remove it.